# Having an Interface provide an instance of a Class that implements it

Tags: java, class, interface, singleton

If I have the interface:

```
public interface Val {
    public NilVal NIL;
}
```

And a singleton class that implements it:

```
public class NilVal implements Val {

    private static NilVal nil = null;

    private NilVal() {
    }

    public static NilVal getInstance(){
        if(nil == null)
            nil = new NilVal();
        return nil;
    }
}
```

How would I go about instantiating NIL as a NilVal object in the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
public interface Val {
    Val NIL = NilVal.getInstance();
}
```

However you could also do

```
public interface Val {
    Val NIL = new NilVal();

    class NilVal implements Val {
        private NilVal() { }
    }
}
```

or even

```
public interface Val {
    Val NIL = NilVal.NIL;

    public enum NilVal implements Val { NIL }
}
```